# How can I force numbers only on a dynamically created field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to restrict a dynamic field to numbers only but if I try:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.numberOnly', function() {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 || (e.keyCode == 65 && (e.ctrlKey ===
            true || e.metaKey === true)) || (e.keyCode >=
            35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
        return;
    }
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode >
            57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. it does work if I replace the top line with:

```
$(".numberOnly").keydown(function(e) {
```

however, that only works for static fields.

Comment: What does the "field"s HTML look like? If it's an input why not just set the type to number?

Comment: `$(document).on('keydown', '.numberOnly', function() {` looks good so my guess is that the dynamically added field does not have the `class="numberOnly"`

Comment: Because I want to just not allow them to put in numbers as I've already validation. Basically, it's in the req doc

Comment: Hi, my dynamic field is added in via jquery and looks like this <input type="text" class="form-control accountNumber numberOnly requiredClass" style="width: 150px"/>

Comment: You didn't pass the event object `e` as a param to the delegated function

Comment: Hi, LcLk, that worked. If you edited that into an answer I'd be happy to mark it correct. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method looks just fine, and should work correctly. There was one small typo that you left out the [EventObject](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) `e` from the delegated event binder ( but included it in the direct event binder, which is why it worked ).

Changing the first line to:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.numberOnly', function(e) {
```

should fix your problem